# Error en transacción en PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, sql, base-de-datos, transacciones

Quiero realizar una venta insertando datos en dos tablas diferentes una llamada Venta y otra llamada detalleventa, pero me marca error al insertar los datos en la tabla llamada detalleventa

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esa es mi base de datos y este mi código de php

```
    <?php
$servidor = "localhost";
$nombredb = "martinez_elnegrito";
$contrasena = "";
$usuario = "root";

$fol = $_POST[ 'folio' ];
$fech = $_POST[ 'fecha' ];
$hor = $_POST[ 'hora' ];
$nombr = $_POST[ 'nombreus' ];
$product = $_POST[ 'idproducto' ];
$cant = $_POST[ 'canti' ];
$conexion = new mysqli($servidor, $usuario, $contrasena, $nombredb);
if ( $conexion->connect_error ) {
    ?>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onClick="regresar()">Regresar</button>
<?php
die( "Error en la BD" );
}

$sql = "BEGIN;";
if($conexion ->query($sql)===FALSE){
    die("ERROR 1");
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO venta (folio,fecha,hora,nombreus) VALUES ('$fol','$fech','$hor','$nombr');";
if($conexion->query($sql)===FALSE){
    $conexion->query("ROLLBACK;");
    die("ERROR 2");
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO detalleventa(idproducto,cantidad) VALUES ('$product','$cant');";
if($conexion->query($sql)===FALSE){
    $conexion->query("ROLLBACK;");
    die("Error 3");
}else{
    $conexion->query("COMMIT;");
    ?>
    <h2>Venta Agregada </h2>
    <?php
    }
$conexion->close();
?>
```

Siempre me marca el error en esta parte

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO detalleventa(idproducto,cantidad) VALUES 
('$product','$cant');";
if($conexion->query($sql)===FALSE){
$conexion->query("ROLLBACK;");
die("Error 3");
```

Muchas gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Si ejecutas desde phpmyadmin la consulta INSERT INTO detalleventa(idproducto,cantidad) VALUES 
(1,1); ¿también te da error?

Comment: En vez de `die ("Error...");` pon `die($conexion->error);` para que te informe del error exacto que está ocurriendo. Puede ser que se está violando la restricción de fila duplicada o que haya un error de consulta, etc. El error exacto te dirá lo que es. Por otra parte, una vez solventado este problema, considera asegurar tu código contra el gravísimo peligro de la Inyección SQL. En las columnas del tipo `INT` debes quitar las comillas simples. Si ambas lo son por ejemplo, la consulta debería ser escrita así: `"INSERT INTO detalleventa(idproducto,cantidad) VALUES 
($product,$cant);"`

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO detalleventa(idproducto,cantidad) VALUES 
('$product','$cant');";
if($conexion->query($sql)===FALSE){
$conexion->query("ROLLBACK;");
die("Error 3");
```

Igual porque estás metiendo la cantidad como string `'$cant'`, casi mejor `$cant` por lo que puedo leer de tu base de datos, podrías hacerlas también preparadas y así te queda mejor, preparas y ejecutas,  pero vamos que tu error creo que es por eso que te comento.